# How to build an AST for Solidity?

Tags: solidity, parser

I'm trying to build a parser for Solidity, and it would help if I could build a working version off of the existing parser. I've tried looking at the source code on [the official git](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/tree/develop/libsolidity/parsing), but I haven't worked on a project of this magnitude before and it's confusing. Could some one tell me how I could isolate the parsing and AST modules so I can read a script and build an AST from it?

(I understand the scope might be a little too broad for this question, but I'd really appreciate any pointers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use `solc --ast`, the compiler will output a json-representation of the AST (this is also included in the npm version of the compiler). Is that enough for your purposes? If not, please come to [gitter](https://gitter.im/ethereum/solidity) to discuss.

Comment: Is there a way to convert an AST back into Solidity code? i.e. for transpilation purposes

Answer (score 3):

In addition to chriseth's answer, there's also the [solidity-parser](https://github.com/ConsenSys/solidity-parser) project which is useful if you A) are developing in a Javascript context, or B) don't want the parser to error if there are unresolved imports (unfortunately `solc --ast` will error if there are imports it cannot find).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tim's answer there's also a [python-solidity-parser](https://github.com/ConsenSys/python-solidity-parser) based on the ANTLR syntax and AST format used in [solidity-parser-antlr](https://github.com/federicobond/solidity-parser-antlr) that you can use if you want to avoid depending on the compiler. Note: compiler AST is the truth.

Answer (score 1):

I have used 3 tools, maybe you can try:

1. https://github.com/iamdefinitelyahuman/py-solc-ast
2. https://github.com/ConsenSys/solc-typed-ast
3. https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/tree/develop/docs/grammar

Answer (score 1):

Use flag `--ast-compact-json`, which gives the "AST of all source files in a compact JSON format."

```
solc --ast-compact-json contract.sol
```